# Clean Scattering borders using cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, shaders, transparency

In forest pack for 3dsmax, they use vray to cut out part of the scattered assets going out of the emitter mesh boundaries.

[image]

It's completely possible to do the same thing with cycles transparency but **only with a texture** projected on a global space.

[image]

I found **no way** to make such boundary filter work with a procedural method, that would for example, analyse the emitter geometry.

Any thoughts on this?
Is this truly impossible to find a non destructive method that don't rely on projected uv-images?

[image]

Comment: Thanks, i was searching for such option

Comment: "Analyze emitter geometry" ... like face of plane (emitter) will be a factor in Z axis for transparency? Or factor should be a shape of another object? It is not clear for me what kind of final shapes are you looking for and how much factor should be procedural and how much controlled or defined by user.

Comment: I meant by that, from grass shader, remove all parts of the grass that is going outside of emitter geometrical boundaries